# HTML5 drag&drop ignore drop and opens file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to open a text file via drag&drop and simple open file button. I managed to get my button working, but have some problems with the drag-drop. As i am droping the file on my dropdown area the file gets opened and is read by the browser not my js-code.

```css
#fileInput {
 display: none;
    }

    #dropBox {
 margin: 15px;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 border: 5px dashed gray;
 border-radius: 8px;
 background: lightyellow;
 background-size: 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 text-align: center;
    }

    #dropBox div {
 margin: 100px 70px;
 color: orange;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/file.css" />

    <script>

    <!-- File processing-->
    function procesFiles(files) {
 
 var file = files[0];
 var reader = new FileReader();
 
 reader.onload = function(e) {
  var output = document.getElementById("fileOutput");
  output.textContent = e.target.result;
 };
 

 reader.readAsText(file);
    }
 

    <!-- File input-->
    function showFileInput() {
 var fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
 fileInput.click();
    }

    <!-- Drop box -->
    var dropBox;

    window.onload = function() {
 dropBox = document.getElementById("dropBox");
 dropBox.ondragenter = ignoreDrag;
 dropBox.ondragover = ignoreDrag;
 dropBox.ondrop = drop;
    }

    function ignoreDrag(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();
    }

    function drop(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();
 
 var data = e.dataTransfer.files;
 var files = data.files;
 
 procesFiles(files);
 
    }
    </script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
  
     <div id="dropBox">
   <div>Drop your file here...</div>
    </div>
  
    <input id="fileInput" type="file" onchange="procesFiles(this.files)"/>
   <button onclick="showFileInput()">Get new file!</button>
  
    <div id="fileOutput" style="width:500px; height:300px;">
    </div>

  
    </body>
    </html>
```

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/file.css" />

<script>

<!-- File processing-->
function procesFiles(files) {

var file = files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
    var output = document.getElementById("fileOutput");
    output.textContent = e.target.result;
};


reader.readAsText(file);
}


<!-- File input-->
function showFileInput() {
var fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
fileInput.click();
}

<!-- Drop box -->
var dropBox;

window.onload = function() {
dropBox = document.getElementById("dropBox");
dropBox.ondragenter = ignoreDrag;
dropBox.ondragover = ignoreDrag;
dropBox.ondrop = drop;
}

function ignoreDrag(e) {
e.stopPropagation;
e.preventDefault;
}

function drop(e) {
e.stopPropagation;
e.preventDefault;

var data = e.dataTransfer.files;
var files = data.files;

procesFiles(files);

}
</script>

</head>
<body>

 <div id="dropBox">
<div>Drop your file here...</div>
</div>

<input id="fileInput" type="file" onchange="procesFiles(this.files)"/>
<button onclick="showFileInput()">Get new file!</button>

<div id="fileOutput" style="width:500px; height:300px;">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

And also my css file:

```
#fileInput {
display: none;
}

#dropBox {
margin: 15px;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border: 5px dashed gray;
border-radius: 8px;
background: lightyellow;
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-align: center;
}

#dropBox div {
margin: 100px 70px;
color: orange;
font-size: 25px;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Do you have any idea, what could be wrong?

--Edit--
I have one more questin - how can block the  from openig the droping file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
e.stopPropagation;   
e.preventDefault;
```

These are supposed to be functions:

```
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have not noticed this typo :)

Comment: No problem, happens to everyone all the time :)